# Is there a way to single out data points in a jammed ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, cluster-analysis

[image: Cluster plot]

This is a ggplot produced by fviz_cluster function. The problem is that I want to single out some data points or even a single one and label it by name. I can easily identify the data points that are on the edges, but what happens for those in the middle of the pack. I thought of approaching this by labelling every data point and then zoom in, but the plot is not interactive and I can't find a way to do that. Any idea on how to approach this would be much appreciated

Here is my code:

```
r=as.data.frame(colnames(df))

remov=c(1,2,5,7,11,14,16,21,23,24,25,26,89,29:54)

df=df[,-remov]

rem=c(2,3,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16)
rownam=as.data.frame(unique(df$Name))
k=df[,-rem]
k= k[!duplicated(df$Name),]
k <- data.frame(k[,-1], row.names = k[,1])

k=na.omit(k)

kme=kmeans(k,centers = 6,nstart = 25)

str(kme)


fviz_cluster(kme, data = k,geom="point")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an easy workaround to make your graph interactive use the ggplotly() function.

install plotly:

```
install.packages("plotly")
library(plotly)

plot <- fviz_cluster(kme, data = k,geom="point")

plot %>% ggplotly()

# or

ggplotly(plot)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this but I get the following error:                                Error: Can't add `ggplotly()` to a ggplot object.  fviz_cluster is a ggplot but I don't seem tobe able to interact with it in any way

Comment: i gave you the worng syntax and its  
plot %>% ggplotly() not                                                                                                          plot + ggplotly()

Comment: Oh yes I tried ggplotly(plot) already. I can run the command without getting an error, but I don't get a plot. The viewer tab appears on the bottom right but it's blank. Could it be because of the size of the dataset?

Comment: Did you try the function on a smaller plot to see if it works? mabye your figure margins are  indeed to large, then you could try to export it to a browser

Comment: Yes it works on a smaller plot. Thank you for your help!

Comment: try following on your big plot: in the viewer panel: export -> save as webpage

Comment: Glad i could help! Have fun exploring your clusters!